# Are makefile relative paths treated the same as gcc relative paths?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I know this sounds like a stupid question, and it is. I'm trying to write a makefile, which builds and links against a static library that I'm writing (this is a unit testing framework). Basically I can't figure out where the working directory of the call to gcc is when I use make.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
./
|-> src
|-> include
|-> project
    |-> Makefile
|-> test
    |-> test.c, test.h
    |-> project
        |-> Makefile
```

So, if I go to the test/project directory and type the following command, I don't seem to have any problems

```
gcc -I../../include -I../../src ../test.c
```

But if I use a makefile with essentially the same configuration (makefile is below), then I get an error along the lines of:

```
gcc -o test ../test.c
In file included from ../test.c:7:0:
../test.h:8:24: fatal error: System.h: No such file or directory
#include "System.h"
```

(System.h is one of my header files located in the `include/` directory).

So here's my question. Since I'm trying to use gcc to compile a file at a different relative path from the makefile, which has includes from a different relative path from itself, what is the proper way to do this with make? Should I change my working directory to the one that contains test.c, and include relative to that directory, or should I put relative paths to everything as if I called gcc from the directory of the makefile?

Here's my makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99 -static -I../../include -I../../src -L$(LIBTARGET) -lmystaticlib
TARGET_APP=test
LIBTARGET = ../../project

all : $(TARGET_APP)

$(TARGET_APP) : library
        $(CC) ${CLAGS} -o $@ ../test.c

library : 
        $(MAKE) -C $(LIBTARGET)
```

Comment: Your makefile has a typo, you're using ${CLAGS} instead of ${CFLAGS}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `${CLAGS}` with `$(CFLAGS)` (parens instead of brackets, fix typo in variable name) in the makefile. As it is now, the `CFLAGS` variable in the makefile is not used. That is the reason that its contents don't show up in the compiler call, and that is the reason that `../../include` is not part of the compiler search path.

Other than that: Unless you did something to change it, the working directory of the compiler call is the directory from which you called make. You can test this by putting a makefile with the following contents:

```
all:
        pwd
```

in a directory, say `/home/user/foo/bar/Makefile`. Then:

```
$ cd /home/user/foo/bar
$ make
/home/user/foo/bar
$ cd ..
$ make -f bar/Makefile
/home/user/foo
```

Comment: `${CFLAGS}` and `$(CFLAGS)` are both valid make variable expansions. Personally I prefer the `$(CFLAGS)` version to avoid confusion with shell variables as much as possible.