# Makefile for linking opencv.framework (I'm not using cmake)

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I use opencv in my project, and now I compile the project into a static library using makefile, but always output 'fatal error: 'cv.h' file not found'. I have searched this site and elsewhere, it's not what I need. I only know a little makefile syntax. What should I do?

**Makefile**

```
LIBS_DIR = ./lib/
OBJS_DIR = ./obj/
DEPENDENT_DIR = ./dependent/

HEADER_PATH = -I./include -I./implement -I.
LIB_PATH = -L./lib

SRCDIRS := $(patsubst ./%, %, $(shell find . -type d))
SRCS_CXX := $(foreach dir, $(SRCDIRS), $(wildcard $(addprefix $(dir)\/*, .cpp)))

OBJS := $(SRCS_CXX:.cpp=.o)

%.o: %.cpp
  @echo "---------- .o begin ----------"
  $(CXX) -c $< $(HEADER_PATH)
  $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIB_PATH)
  mv $@ $(OBJS_DIR)

%.d: %.cpp
  @echo "---------- dependent begin ----------"
  @set -e; \
  rm -f $@; \
  $(CXX) -MM $< > $@.tmp; \
  sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.tmp > $@; \
  rm -f $@.tmp
  mv $@ $(DEPENDENT_DIR)

-include $(DEPS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
  rm -f obj/*.o lib/*.a dependent/*.d
  rm -rf SunWS_cache
```

**In my file**

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

[File directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSNZ0.jpg)

[Used makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlPZ7.jpg)

**New error**

I modified the `HEADER_PATH` like `HEADER_PATH = -I./include/opencv -I./include/opencv2 -I./implement -I.` but a new error appeared, `fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core_c.h' file not found`.

I try to add a new subfolder path like `-I./include/opencv -I./include/opencv2 -I./include/opencv2/core -I./implement -I.` this error is still being output, `-I` command doesn't automatically find the path to the subfolder? am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header paths are `HEADER_PATH = -I./include -I./implement -I.`

Inside the `include` folder you show in the attachment you have 2 subfolders `opencv` and `opencv2`.

When including the `cv.h` file is included directly without the subfolders.
For the compiler to find the files you either need to add the subfolders on the `HEADER_PATH` like `HEADER_PATH = -I./include/opencv -I./include/opencv2 -I./implement`
 or you need to `#include <opencv/cv.h>`, that if `cv.h` is directly inside the `opencv` subfolder.

Side note: you have a typo in the folder `denpendent`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped me, and so sorry for the misspelling of this folder name. After I modified `HEADER_PATH` , a new problem appeared. The problem is above.

Comment: `./include/opencv2` is a relative path. The paths are relative from the directory you call make from. In [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024215/7607456) they show an example of the path changing depending on the folder from which make is called

Comment: You are right, thanks again. I solved this error, maybe the new error caused by my source code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this error and compiled successfully, I still use `CMake`. but after I successfully compiled with `CMake`, I can use the `Makefile` again to compile. I think it was my own mistake, @zomeck's answer helped me.

**This is my CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(library_name)

add_definitions(-Wall)

set(OPENCV_PATH ../sdk3/opencv3.0.0)
set(OPENCL_PATH ../sdk3/opencl)

link_directories(
    ${OPENCL_PATH}/bin
    ${OPENCV_PATH}
)
link_libraries(
    ${OPENCV_PATH}/opencv2.framework
    ${OPENCL_PATH}/bin/OpenCL.DLL
)

include_directories(
    ./
    ./implement
    ${OPENCV_PATH}/include
    ${OPENCV_PATH}/include/opencv
    ${OPENCL_PATH}/include/CL
)

set(SOURCES_FILES
    HS_Process.cpp
    implement/iclear/H_Proc.cpp
)

add_library(library_name STATIC ${SOURCES_FILES})

target_link_libraries(library_name opencv2 OpenCL)
```

**New Makefile after @zomeck's answer**

```
# The following is modified
SDK_PATH = ../sdk3
OPENCL_PATH = ../sdk3/opencl
OPENCV_PATH = ../sdk3/opencv3.0.0/include

vpath = %.h implement : %.h $(OPENCV_PATH) : %.h $(OPENCV_PATH)/opencv : %.h $(OPENCL_PATH) : %.h $(CALCTIME_PATH)

HEADER_PATH = \
-I. \
-I./implement \
-I$(OPENCV_PATH) \
-I$(OPENCV_PATH)/opencv \
-I$(OPENCV_PATH)/opencv2 \
-I$(OPENCL_PATH)/include/CL \

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "---------- .o begin ----------"
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(HEADER_PATH) $< -o $@
    mv $@ $(OBJS_DIR)
```